# geting error while creating an instance of a class in framework in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS development ,, i am facing a problem while creating a instance of a class .

i have a framework named as unknown.framework and it has a class Abc.h

when i am creating a a instane of that class , application is crashing .

code is .

```
IN secondAppDelegate.h

#import <unknownToolkit/unknown.h>


    @interface secondAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
    {
        Abc *method;

    }

    @property (strong, nonatomic)Abc *method;


In secondAppDelegate.m


   Abc *method = [Abc sharedInstance];
   [method callAnInstanceMethod];
```

Where unknown.frmaework is  a private framework and Abc.h is class.

```
and the error report is :
2013-05-17 14:48:58.574 AbcDemo[1832:12b03] -[__NSArrayI mapUsingBlock:usingFilter:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8220a70
2013-05-17 14:48:58.600 AbcDemo[1832:12b03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI mapUsingBlock:usingFilter:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8220a70'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1d49012 0x1335e7e 0x1dd44bd 0x1d38bbc 0x1d3894e 0x5ab60 0x21f19 0x2bda 0x277157 0x277747 0x27894b 0x289cb5 0x28abeb 0x27c698 0x1ca4df9 0x1ca4ad0 0x1cbebf5 0x1cbe962 0x1cefbb6 0x1ceef44 0x1ceee1b 0x27817a 0x279ffc 0x28dd 0x2805)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

and the code is crashing in  iphonesimiulator -> user/include -> dispactch -> once.h

and the line ,where code is crashing is :

```
_dispatch_once(dispatch_once_t *predicate, dispatch_block_t block)
{
    if (DISPATCH_EXPECT(*predicate, ~0l) != ~0l) {
        dispatch_once(predicate, block);
    }
}
```

Please help me

thanks in advance.

Comment: It says very clear that you are trying to call a selector mapUsingBlock: on a NSArray which doesnt have this selector method.

Answer (score 0):

```
-[__NSArrayI mapUsingBlock:usingFilter:]: unrecognized selector ....
```

This ,essage say you try to call method `mapUsingBlock:usingFilter:` from an object of NSArray class.
Maybe somewhere you alloc your variable as `NSArray`. Without more code i cant say anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your unknown.framework. You have used ABCDemo where you have used `mapUsingBlock:` method. You have to correct it else post your full code. Then I will rectify it.

Comment: AbcDemo is project name and i havnt used any mapUsingBlock: method .it  may be getting called from framework , i am only using above two lines code in app delegate.

Comment: @h.kishan, may be you don't, but a 3rd party library which you're using?